# -rwxr-xr-x@ meaning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, mac-osx, capistrano, file-permissions

I have a file with an @ after the permissions

```
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 riccardotacconi  staff   215 14 Sep 14:21 Capfile
```

Do you know its meaning.

I am deploying a Rails application using Capistrano. That Gemfile is not copies, although it is committed in the SVN repository. Very strange.

Comment: This might give a hint.  It's for Mac, but it's based on FreeBSD which is similar to Unix/Linux: http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2008/12/24/what-is-the-significance-of-plus-and-at-in-mac-os-x-file-permission-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using OS X (newer than 10.4), the `@` symbol denotes the file has extended attributes associated with it. (See Stewie's answer for detail.)

To list the extended attribute, use

```
ls -l@
```

From the man page for `ls`:

```
-@  Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.
```

You should see something like the following -

```
(somesystem):~ user$ ls -al@ /
...
drwxr-xr-x@   6 root   wheel       204 Sep 27 12:00 private
 com.apple.FinderInfo       32
```

If you need to dig deeper than that, use `xattr -l`

Answer (score 13):

The "@" sign -- which is not documented in the manual page for ls(1) indicates that the file has extended attributes. You can use the command 'xattr -l ' to show them

Quote from : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes

Extended file attributes is a file system feature that enables users to associate computer files with metadata not interpreted by the filesystem, whereas regular attributes have a purpose strictly defined by the filesystem (such as permissions or records of creation and modification times).

Answer (score 3):

`-rwxr-xr-x` for a regular file whose user class has full permissions and whose group and others classes have only the read and execute permissions.

on osx

ls command now displays a "@" character after the permissions string for each file that has extended attributes

Answer (score 1):

You have extended attributes on that file.  Run

```
ls -le
```

to get more detail.

Comment: It isn't the ACL permissions (those have a +).  The @ symbol indicates extended attributes, aka metadata.

Comment: using ls -le I get ls: invalid option -- e

Answer (score 1):

Is this on OSX? See the discussion [here.](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=5791060)

Relevant part:

> The "@" sign -- which is not documented in the manual page for ls(1) -- indicates that the file has extended attributes. You can use the command 'xattr -l ' to show them. It seems that a lot of Finder information, which ought to be stored in the catalog, is now in extended attributes.

Comment: if I run xattr I get a command not found

Comment: xattr should be located at /usr/bin/xattr